# Filling <select> with dynamic list

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am making a MVC 4 website that displays dynamic data. I have a search feature where they can enter an Id to a input box and only view the info pertaining to that Id. Well I would like to limit there searching capabilities by using a `<select>` list so only valid options can be chosen.

This is the code I wrote:

```
<select>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <option value='@Html.ValueFor(modelItem => item.ResponseIdentifier)'></option>
    }
</select>
```

I'm just trying to grab the Id and use it as the dropdown values in my select list. However, all i'm getting is empty space in the dropdown.

I'm new to web programming and not very familiar with MVC. I tried a couple other Methods to grab the into for the value, but none worked. If anyone has any tips that'd be great. Thank you Stack Overflowers! :)

Comment: The text to be displayed must be put between the two option tags. No text, empty space. Btw i can't see the link with JavaScript...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the `value` and `text` of `select` html control. The sintaxe is:

`<option value='your value'>text</option>`

Try something like this:

```
<select>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <option value='@item.ResponseIdentifier'>@item.ResponseIdentifier</option>
    }
</select>
```

Or, in my opinion it is better. Your action on the controller, you could define a key on the [`ViewBag`](http://weblogs.asp.net/hajan/archive/2010/12/11/viewbag-dynamic-in-asp-net-mvc-3-rc-2.aspx) to fil lthe dropdownList, for sample:

```
ViewBag.Cities = new SelectList(new[]
{
    new { Id = "1", Name = "New York" },
    new { Id = "2", Name = "São Paulo" },
    new { Id = "3", Name = "London" },
}, "Id", "Name");
```

To fill this ViewBag, it could come from a database or xml file, anywhere. In your View, your could use this item on ViewBag to fill a DropDownList using the `Html` helpers, for sample:

```
@Html.DropDownList("City", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Cities, new { style = "max-width: 600px;" })
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are searching for has been discussed in 
[this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11261590/mvc-razor-foreach)

```
<select>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <option value="@item.ResponseIdentifier"></option>
}
</select>
```

should work