# mvc model inside jquery code

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core-mvc

I need to add foreach loop and add model data instead of this hardcoded data. I don't know how to add it inside javascript code with jQuery.

```
 @model  IEnumerable<HR.Models.Officials>


   @foreach (var item in Model)
        {




                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id),
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.parentId),
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
    }
<script type="text/javascript">
        var peopleElement = document.getElementById("people");
        var orgChart = new getOrgChart(peopleElement, {
            primaryFields: ["name", "title", "phone", "mail"],
            photoFields: ["image"],
            dataSource: [
                { id: 1, parentId: null, name: "Amber McKenzie", title: "CEO", phone: "678-772-470", mail: "lemmons@jourrapide.com", adress: "Atlanta, GA 30303", image: "images/f-11.jpg" } ]
        });
    </script>
```

I need to add a foreach loop with my model and add model instead of this hardcoded data.
For example `id:1 = id:@model.id`. I need it in the foreach loop. Kindly need someone to guide me

Comment: If this is a view then just pull the data from the db in the controller method and load it using razor.

Comment: but how i can load data inside jquery script? can i use foreach loop inside    dataSource: [...?

Comment: You could do it inside or define `dataSource:[]` and then in a razor for each loop do `dataSource.push({...})`.

Comment: Note, it is a razor foreach loop NOT a javascript for loop.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11261590/mvc-razor-foreach

Comment: can you give me little practical example how i can use it?

Comment: Sure, but fix your `@model iEnumerable`.  Should be `@model iEnumerable<someClass>`.  Then also post what your class definition is so I can use it in my example.

Comment: i have edit my post can you check foreach loop i need this kind of loop inside dataasource where i have hardcore data now

Comment: Just convert your model to a javascript array. - Refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48689889/how-to-bind-mvc-model-data-to-html-data-attribute/48696024#48696024) for an example

Answer (score 1):

This is one option:

```
@model  IEnumerable<HR.Models.Officials>


@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id),
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.parentId),
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
}
<script type="text/javascript">
    var peopleElement = document.getElementById("people");
    var orgChart = new getOrgChart(peopleElement, {
        primaryFields: ["name", "title", "phone", "mail"],
        photoFields: ["image"],
        dataSource: [
            @for(var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
            {
                <text>
                    { id: @(Model[i].Id), name: "@(Model[i].name)", parentId: @(Model[i].parentId) }@(i < Model.Count - 1 ? "," : "")
                </text>
            }
        ]
    });
</script>
```

Note:  If the value coming in needs to be a string in the javascript then you need to wrap quotes around it, like with `"@(Model[i].name)"`.  Because these are in the declaration of the array, the objects need a `,` between them which is why I made it a for loop instead of a foreach (though it could be done with a foreach as well).

Comment: thanks i will implement this code, if i get any problem i will get back to you

Comment: I just noticed that I was missing a closing paren after `parentId`.  Try now.

Comment: `@model  IEnumerable<HR.Models.Official>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var peopleElement = document.getElementById("people");
    var orgChart = new getOrgChart(peopleElement, {
        primaryFields: ["name", "title", "phone", "mail"],
        photoFields: ["image"],
        dataSource: [
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {

            
                <text>
                    {id: @(item.EmpId), name: "@(item.Name)", parentId: @(item.Id) }
                </text>
            }
        ]
    });
</script>`

Comment: You are missing the commas between the elements of the array.  If you inspect the page you'll see the javascript error.  I used `@(i < Model.Count - 1 ? "," : "")` to put the commas in.

Answer (score 0):

Create something like this in a static class:

```
public static IHtmlContent ToJS(this IHtmlHelper htmlHelper, object obj)
{
    return htmlHelper.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj));
}
```

In your "_ViewImports.cshtml" also you can import `System.Linq` if needed.

Now you can simply do this:

```
<script type = "text/javascript" >
    var peopleElement = document.getElementById("people");
    var orgChart = new getOrgChart(peopleElement, {
        primaryFields: ["name", "title", "phone", "mail"],
        photoFields: ["image"],
        dataSource: @Html.ToJS(Model);
</script>
```

If you want to customize your array object, you can import `Linq` mentioned above and set `dataSource` this way:

```
dataSource: @Html.ToJS(Model.Select(m => new { m.id, m.name, m.parentId, ... }));
```

Comment: where this static class i should put?

Comment: For convince put it directly inside the web project (no folder). Class can have any name