# display the multiple images from database using array

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

**Hi Guys I am trying to Display the images from database I save the images in the database but it not display any thing how can i fix this here in my Code**

**this is my model view**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Archive.Models
{
    public class Inbox
    {
        [Key]

        public int Id { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> Files { get; set; }


        public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
        public object UserId { get; internal set; }
    }
}
```

**and here details**

```
    namespace Archive.Models
{
    public class AllFiles
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ContentType{ get; set; }
        public byte[] Imagebytes { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**here i Convert**

```
using System.Web;
using System.IO;

namespace FileUpload.Service
{
    public class FileUploadService
    {
        // GET: AllFiles
        public void saveFileDetails(HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            AllFiles newfile = new AllFiles();
            newfile.ContentType = file.ContentType;
            newfile.Imagebytes = ConvertToBytes(file);
            ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
            {
                db.AllFiless.Add(newfile);
                db.SaveChanges();      
            }
        }
        public byte[] ConvertToBytes(HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            byte[] imagebytes = null;
            BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(file.InputStream);
            imagebytes = reader.ReadBytes((int)file.ContentLength);
            return imagebytes;
        }
    }
}
```

**and here is my Controller**

```
        public async Task<ActionResult> Create(Inbox model)
    {

        var currentUser = await manager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            model.User = currentUser;

            FileUploadService service = new FileUploadService();
            foreach (var item in model.Files)
            {
                service.saveFileDetails(item);
            }

                var max = new Inbox();

            db.Inboxs.Add(model);
            db.SaveChanges();
            string url = Url.Action("List");
            return Json(new { success = true, url = url });
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

**and this is my view details**

```
    @foreach(var image in Model)
{
    var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(image.Files);
    var imgSrc = String.Format("data:{0};base64,{1}",image.ContentType ,base64);
    <img src="@imgSrc"/>
}
```

i am try to display images here but is not show up what is problem guys please guys i am trying this so hard  i asked here but i did't get the [images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53101963/i-need-just-to-display-the-multiple-images-i-insert/53151836#53151836)

**the image in database it saved like this**
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ts9XK.png)

Comment: **How** are those images saved? Blobs in the Database? Files in the FileSystem? Is the folder public/do you got a HTTP handler to serve those images to WebBrowsers?

Comment: Where is the GET action method code for the view where you are trying to display the images ?

Comment: i am  trying to display the images in a  inbox controller i don't have  a get action to display  how can i do that

Comment: For the request, you need a GET action which gets the data and pass it to the view. Is your current code properly saving the data ? I see many `ApplicationDbContext` objects inside the save code.

Comment: Shyju  can you help me do  this please bro

Comment: no one really  ?