# How to Bind a model based on a parameter in WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am working on an API in which I can receive a payload with several possible types based on their type. For example

```
public class Item{};

public class Book : Item{
    public string author { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
}

public class Movie{
     public string title { get; set; }
     public string studio { get; set; } 
}

public class VideoGame{
     public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class StoreItem{
    public string upc { get; set; }
    public double price { get; set }
    public Item item { get; set; }
}
```

What I would like to do is have My controller being able to accept a `StoreItem` object

for example

```
[HttpPost("postItemForSale")]
public object Post(StoreIrem item)
```

The way this would be resolved is base on a type enum, so the request json will look like this:

```
{
 upc   : "12345",
 price : "99.99",
 item  : { 
          type   : "videoGame",
          name   : "minesweeper"
         }
}
```

My question is there anyway I can define a mapping, lets assume that the type field is an enum and I have a corresponding Model for each representation.

Comment: What do you want? are you asking for polymorphic model binding?

Comment: Yes, prety much this.

Comment: First, off you should probably create a common class they inherit from i.e Movie and Video Game should be an item.  If you want to operate on these universally, video game shouldn't be called name it should be called title to be consistent.  I've written an interface binder here a few years ago which matches based on existing properties in the JSON, https://stackoverflow.com/a/46199777/1938988 you can use this for now but if you're doing this in production you should modify it to check if it has a type property first and use that to avoid the reflection, alternatively you can create type map

Comment: Thanks, This is just a made up example to show what I mean. I am always going to have a type parameter to indicate what type of Item it is. my real question is how do I use that to map to a concrete type.  Even if I don't follow this approach, I wouldn't know how to create multiple controller entry points based on the type parameter

Comment: in the answer i've provided the model binder automatically chooses the type based on the properties in the JSON string.  You can easily have it use they type explicitly for instantiation, then you just need to cast to that type, but TBH you should just make a base service which has your logic for Items, and have 3 controllers inherit from it.  Then from your complex type you can just call right server.  Ideally you shouldn't even use a complex type, read up on Rest Architecture, it will make api creation a lot easier